# C# Multiple ItemSources in Datagrid

Tags: c#, xaml

I used to have the following DataGrid:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource tableStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding PagedView}">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=EventID, StringFormat='#{0}'}" CanUserSort="True" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" Width="Auto" Header="EventID"/>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EventDescription}" CanUserSort="True" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" Width="Auto" Header="Description"/>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EventStatu.Description}" CanUserSort="True" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" Width="Auto" Header="Status"/>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="Detector.Track.TrackName" Width="Auto" Header="Track">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Detector.Track.TrackName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Detector.DetectorID, StringFormat=' ({0})'}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>             
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding StartedOn.LocalDateTime, StringFormat={StaticResource DateFormat}}" CanUserSort="True" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" Header="Started" Width="Auto"/>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EndedOn.LocalDateTime, FallbackValue=N/A, StringFormat={StaticResource DateFormat}}" CanUserSort="True" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" Header="Stopped" Width="Auto"/>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

And the .cs

```
private void EventsLoaded(LoadOperation<Event> loadOperation)
{
    events.Clear();

    if(loadOperation.HasError)
    {
        loadOperation.MarkErrorAsHandled();
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (Event evnt in loadOperation.Entities)
        {
            events.Add(evnt);//For adding the whole event row
        }
    }
}
```

This gave me the following rows as a result:

```
EventID     Description     Status      Track       Started       Stopped
```

Now this is all correct and working. However, i want to add a extra column with the difference in time between **Started** and **Stopped**.

For this, i have added the following:

In the designer i added:

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=timediff}" CanUserSort="True" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" Header="Duration" Width="Auto"/>
```

In the .Cs i added:

```
string Difference = string.Empty;
TimeSpan duration = evnt.EndedOn.Value.Subtract(evnt.StartedOn);
if (duration.Days > 0)
{
    Difference += string.Format("Event duration: {0} day(s) and {1} hour(s) \r\n",
    duration.Days, duration.Hours);
}
else if (duration.Hours > 0)
{
    Difference += string.Format("Event duration: {0} hour(s) and {1} minute(s) \r\n",
    duration.Hours, duration.Minutes);
}
else
{
    Difference += string.Format("Event duration: {0} minute(s) \r\n",
    duration.Minutes);
}

List<TimeInfo> timeinfo = new List<TimeInfo>();
timeinfo.Add(new TimeInfo() { timediff = Difference });
```

And

```
public class TimeInfo
{
    public string timediff { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when i run the program again, it shows me the following columns:

```
EventID     Description     Status      Track       Started       Stopped       Duration
```

Everything is filled in except **Duration**.
When i add the following in my .Cs code:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = timeinfo;
```

and run the application, it only fills in the duration field, and leaves the rest empty.

Is there a possibility that i can show both of the itemsources in 1 grid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding to Property and ItemSource with DataGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766180/binding-to-property-and-itemsource-with-datagrid)

Answer (score 0):

i red your problem. How i did understand your ItemSource can´t read Difference property. In first case you access to "dataGrid" where you say that he`s ItemSource is "timeinfo" and in second case you are having "PagedView" list where are your propertyes.

First suggestion is to orrient to MVVM concept, that means (for example):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PagedView}" DataContext="{Binding YourClassName}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GridViewColumn Width="200">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding EventID}">
                     <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding EventDescription}">
                </Grid>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>    
</ListView>
```

I took your first and secon Colums as example. But for rest you cann add more colums in ColumnDefinition and down define more TextBlocks. And that is your **View**. Class YourClassName represents your ListView **View-Model** :

```
public class YourClassName {

    public YourClassName(string eventId, string eventDescr)
    {
        EventID = eventId;
        EventDescription = eventDescr;
    }
    private string mEventID;
    public string EventID{
        get { return mEventID; }
        set { SetProperty(ref mEventID, value); }
    }

            private string mEventDescription;
    public string EventDescription{
        get { return mEventDescription; }
        set { SetProperty(ref mEventDescription, value); }
    }
}
```

Now you need Property of your Class:

```
private List<YourClassName> mPagedView;
public List<YourClassName> PagedView {
    get { return mPagedView; }
    set { SetProperty(ref mPagedView, value); }
}
```

In your MainViewModel for example in Constructor you make instance of your class:

```
PageView = new List<YourClassName>();
PageView.Add("MYID","Blabla");
```

In this case you avoid x:Name which is public and i use it only when i must.

I hope that it helped at least a little bit.

Regards!